How to make sure for the generalization with very very small data?
I have 21 observations with more than 10000 features. The problem is binary classification and is balanced.  Using feature selection method, I found 5 features. Then, I have 21 observations with 5 features. I know the data is so small but in medical data, It usually happen.
My question is, In general, how to make sure that the model is not overfitting in such small sample data and has the generalization power to unseen data.

Estimating 5 unkowns (for 5 weight variables for each indpependent variable) with only 20 sample size will lead to a low significance for weight estimates. This means the sample does not represent population characteristics and the model will not generalize well to the unseen data. Some statisticians say 20 observations per independent variable to achieve significant results.
